# LAS/LAZ parser for NodeJS

Tags: lidar, las, node-js, laz

I cannot find any popular libraries for parsing (reading into memory) of LAS or LAZ  (lidar data) files in NodeJS (desktop Javascript)

https://github.com/yuyou/liblas4node/blob/master/lib/liblas.js

This depends on liblas which is deprectaed/replaced by PDAL, for which, no js bindings exist. Are there any other libs out there? npm search is a little clusmy, since 'las' is found in many completely non related packages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/hobu/laz-perf contains an alternative implementation of LASzip that can be compiled to WASM and JavaScript using Emscripten. It is used by Potree and PlasioJS to provide LAZ support in JavaScript.